# ¿Como traer las recetas que contengan las categorias que yo le pase? Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Necesito traerme las recetas que contengan estas categorias, pero est consulta me trae las categorias con las recetas, que estan relacionadas a estas y solo necesito las recetas y que estas no se repiten por cada categoria, esta es mi consulta

```
$where = Recetas::with('categorias')->whereIn('nombre',  ["Comida venga","Comida Carnivora"]);
```

Y estas son las tablas es una relacion de muchos a muchos.

La tabla categoria.

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('nombre')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

La tabla Recetas.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recetas', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('dificultad');
        $table->float('tiempo');
        $table->smallInteger('comensales');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->text('imagen');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

La tabla pivot.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias_recetas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('recetas_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('categorias_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('categorias_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->foreign('recetas_id')->references('id')->on('recetas');
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿La relación está funcionando y solo no logras hacer la consulta?

Comment: Si la relacion funciona , lo que no se como hacer la consulta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes [Consultar la existencia de relación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para obtener solo las recetas que estén relacionadas a una categoría donde el nombre coincida con alguno de los elementos en el array `["Comida venga", "Comida Carnivora"]`:

```
$recetas = Recetas::whereHas('categorias', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('nombre', ["Comida venga", "Comida Carnivora"]);
})->get();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvio de mucho.