# Aplicar whereIn a una Relación en Laravel

Tags: laravel, json, eloquent, orm, laravel-7

Tengo el siguiente problema, implica la tabla *users*,*plants* y *plant_user* (pivot table), con las siguientes relaciones en los modelos correpondientes

*Modelo User*

```
public function plants()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Plant::class);
  }
```

*Modelo Plant*

```
public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }
```

Quiero realizar una consulta en la que dado un arreglo que contenga los *id* de ciertas plantas pueda obtener todos los usuarios relacionados con esas plantas.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
$plants= [1,3,6];

$users = User::with(['plants' => function ($query) use($plants) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $plants);
      }])->get();
```

El problema con esta consulta es cuando las plantas de algún usuario no coinciden con las del arreglo y el usuario es incluido en la respuesta con su relación *plants* vacía.
Adjunto un ejemplo de un usuario que coincide con al menos una planta y uno que no coincide con ninguna.

```
            {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Joy Champlin",
            "email": "lfriesen@example.org",
            "email_verified_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "verified": 0,
            "photo": "1.jpg",
            "role_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "plants": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bryon Runolfsson",
            "email": "greenholt.esteban@example.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "verified": 1,
            "photo": "2.jpg",
            "role_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-04T02:43:56.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "plants": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "plant_code": "ARA0",
                    "plant_name": "Planta Ramos Arizpe",
                    "flag": 1,
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": 1,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            ]
        },
```

La consulta que busco es una donde solo se listen los usuarios cuyas plantas relacionadas coincidan al menos en un elemento con el arreglo **$plants**

Comment: Agregale un `whereHas` de la misma forma que tienes el `with`. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/356386/92278. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Gracias @porloscerrosΨ  efectivanamente la consulta quedó de la siguiente forma :                                                                                                            
 ``` $users = User::whereHas('plants', function ($query) use ($plants) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $plants);
      }))->get();```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la respuesta mencionada en el comentario, modifiqué la consulta y quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
$users = User::whereHas('plants', function ($query) use ($plants) {
   $query->whereIn('id', $plants);
}))->get();
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada por favor