# Necesito filtrar datos relacionados en eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

ProductSale vendria ser como el detalle de la venta y es la tabla intermediaria entre ventas y productos.
En la siguiente consulta deseo obtener los detalles de ventas en donde la venta esta activa y le pertenece al usuario que le paso por parametro y tambien desearia obtener esos datos paginados.

```php
public function history(User $user){    
        $this->authorize('view',$user);
        
        $details=ProductSale::with(['product','sale'=>function($query)use($user){
            $query->where('sales.enabled','=',1)->where('sales.user_id','=',$user->id);
        }])->paginate(4);

        return $details;
        
        return view('home.users.history',compact('details'));
    }
```

pero como muestra la imagen, en los detalles de venta en donde sales.enabled no es 1, carga la relacion sale como null, directamente no deseo mostrar aquellos datos donde sale sea null[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendría que usar whereHas, además de with. Dale una mirada a esta pregunta/respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356381/como-traer-las-recetas-que-contengan-las-categorias-que-yo-le-pase-eloquent/356386#356386

Comment: Si, tiene algo de malo eso? Porque se me facilito a la hora de imprimir los datos con un solo foreach

Comment: Claro yo lo hice asi, pero en una venta puede que ocurra que se compren varios productos y ademas que una venta solo le pertenece a un usuario, entonces a la hora de mostrar los productos y ademas atributos de la tabla intermedia como que se me complico imprimir esos resultados

Comment: he seguido la sugerencia de @porloscerrosΨ y lo he solucionado, muchas gracias!

Comment: ademas de usar with debia usar whereHas, yo filtraba los datos de la relacion en el metodo with pero era con el metodo whereHas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolví mi problema usando el método whereHas que permite realizar condiciones al modelo relacionado, que en mi caso necesitaba para mi modelo sale(venta), que la venta este activa y que le pertenezca al usuario que paso por parámetro

```php
public function history(User $user){    
        $this->authorize('view',$user);
        
        $details=ProductSale::with(['product','sale'])->whereHas('sale',function($query)use($user){
            $query->whereEnabled(1)->whereUserId($user->id);
        })->paginate(3);
        
        
        return view('home.users.history',compact('details'));
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ^-^