# Devolver todos los Posts que pertenezcan a una categoria XXX

Tags: laravel

Estoy usando Laravel 8
Tengo 2 Modelos ( Posts and categories ) , con una relacion muchos a muchos a traves de una tabla pivote.

Model Post

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
            ->as('categories');
    }
```

La estructura de datos que me devuelve cuando traigo todos los posts ( Post::all(); )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito traer todos los posts que pertenezcan a una categoria xxx.

He intentado hacerlo con estas consultas pero no me funciona

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->where('categories.categories.category_id == 1)->get();
$posts = Post::with('categories')->where('categories.categories:category_id == 1)->get();
```

Como seria la forma correcta? Gracias

Comment: ***What would be the correct way?***, the correct way is to ask in spanish. You are at [es.so]. Please translate your question, otherwise it will be closed. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Hi there! The correct way is to post your question in Spanish.

Comment: Perdon, pense que estaba en stackoverflow de habla inglesa, ya esta traducido

Comment: La categoría la filtras por nombre o por id @Alberto ?

Comment: por id . Gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como traer las recetas que contengan las categorias que yo le pase? Eloquent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356381/como-traer-las-recetas-que-contengan-las-categorias-que-yo-le-pase-eloquent)

Comment: @porloscerros me salvaste la vida! Es eso! gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que expones no parece la adecuada ya que estarías obteniendo *todos los posts con las categorías a las que están asociados*.

Dado lo anterior entonces, deberás invertir algunas cosas en la query original y colocarla así:

```
 Category::with('posts')->findOrFail($idCategory);
```

De esta manera deberías estar consiguiendo:

- Un objeto con los datos de la categoría filtrada por id
- Una colección con posts que esta categoría tiene asociados

Comment: Muchas gracias @betaM . Como menciones funciona pero me devuelve los datos con otra estructura.Estoy con livewire y el problema es que estoy obteniendo todos los posts en un datatable y una vez cargado quiero filtrar por categorias. Entonces si devuelvo a la vista las Categorias como tu propones me da error. De que otra forma se puede hacer para devolver la misma estructura de datos que cuando hago un post::all() ??

Comment: ¿y qué error te da @Alberto? ahora si quieres dar ese filtro a tu datatable entonces solo debes adaptar esto que propongo, mandas al componente el valor de la variable que deberías tener vinculada, ese te generará el filtro

Comment: Me da error por la propia estructura, ya que el datatable imprime por ejemplo, el post->title , y con la solucion que me has dicho esos datos no vienen asi. Perdona mi ignorancia pero lo que me dices es que cree un objeto nuevo, con los datos que recibe la consulta y lo pase modificado tal y como lo necesito a la vista? Es que no me parece muy optimo..no?

Comment: Lo inicial no me dice mucho, debes ser explicito en mencionar que error te da, edita tu pregunta y ahi agregalo